# mariadb installation issue - ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not loaded

Tags: database, ubuntu, installation, plugins, mariadb

1. using remote ubuntu server 16.04.7
2. install mariadb by sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
3. when I run `sudo mysql -u root` , I get the following error: "ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not loaded "
4. when I run
   `sudo mysql_secure_installation` 
   and when I press enter for "Enter Current password for root (enter for none)" ,  I get the same error.

I tried several several solutions suggested here and there as follows:

1. completely uninstall & reinstall (multiple times)
2. add

   [mysqld]
   default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password

in my.cnf

3. `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`  and `sudo mysql -u root`

None of above worked. Please help..

Comment: caching_sha2_password authentication is only supported by MySQL server, so you're not connected to a MariaDB server.